# Bash: How to create an alias in .bashrc for awk with parameters

Tags: bash, awk, alias, function

I'm trying to add an alias in .bashrc file as follows:

```
...
alias cutf="_cutf"
...
_cutf() {
   awk 'NR >= $2 && NR <= $3 { print }' < $1
}
```

(The function's goal is to show the content of the lines whose number is between $2 and $3 for the $1 file)

When I call cutf in a new bash session I get no output.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2 and $3 are in single quotes. Shell doesn't expand variables in single quotes, so they get interpreted by `awk`. Switch to double quotes:

```
awk "NR >= $2 && NR <= $3 { print }" < "$1"
```

Note that you can achieve the same with

```
sed -n 'X,Yp' file
```

where X and Y are the line numbers, or similarly in Perl with

```
perl -ne 'print if X .. Y' file
```

which are both so short you probably don't need a function for them.

Answer (score 1):

You should not let the shell expand variables within your awk statement. Variables such as $2 and $3 have a special meaning within awk.

```
_cutf() {
   awk -v start="$2" -v stop="$3" 'NR >= start && NR <= stop { print }' "$1"
}
```

or you could write it like this

```
_cutf() {
   awk 'NR >= start && NR <= stop { print }' start="$2" stop="$3" "$1"
}
```

Comment: Does the start and stop parameters make awk more efficient -in my case-?